# Object destructing ES6 class

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, ecmascript-6

How can I properly apply object destructing for the methods in ES6 classes

**user.ts**

```
import { Request, Response } from "express";

export class User {

  constructor (){
      Object.assign(this,{
          root:this.root,
          get:this.get
      })
  }  
  public  root(req: Request, res: Response) { 
    res.status(200).send({
      message: "DEFAULT request successful!!"
    });
  }
  public get(req: Request, res: Response){
    res.status(200).send({
        message: "USER request  successful!!"
      });
  }

}

export const user = new User();
```

And i am import like this

```
import  {root,get} from './user'
```

But it will be thrown has no exported member error

**UPDATE**

Based on comments i changed my export to the following

```
let obj = new User();

export const user = {
    root:obj.root,
    get:obj.get
}
```

But still the same error

Comment: You aren't exporting anything named `get`, so `import { .. get }` won't work

Comment: @CertainPerformance I didn't get it

Comment: You're importing `get` but you never exported anything called `get`

Comment: @iambatman you are exporting `user`, hence you should `import { user } from './user'`. You have no export named `get` and `root`. Destructing and export are not exactly the same thing.

Comment: You are mixing destructuring and import/export non-default stuff notations.

Comment: Same as root, will it work if you import `{user.get}` ?

Comment: @MoadEnnagi I don't think so. The cleverest and most appropriate way to do, to me, is: `import { user } from './user'; let { root, get } = user;`. Otherwise, root and get needs to be exported, not sure whether the op wants to export the `user` instance method or the `User` class methods (either shared or singleton)

Comment: `import {}` is not destructuring. It just looks like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to export `root` and `get` - destructure your `export` line:

```
export const { root, get } = new User();
```

If you also want to export a user:

```
export const user = new User();
export const { root, get } = user;
```

You could also just import `user` and manually create the functions:

```
import { user } from "./user";
const { root, get } = user;
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `import { user } from "./user";`? It's not a default export, right?

Comment: Oh yes @briosheje.